# How to convert how to convert " Tuesday April 27, 2021" date in format like '2021-04-27T00:00:00' in apex?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-apex

How to convert how to convert  `"Tuesday April 27, 2021"`  date in format like  `'2021-04-27T00:00:00'` in Apex.

Comment: This seems more like an Oracle SQL question than Apex?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a two-step conversion.

Value you have is a string; first you have to convert it to a valid `DATE` datatype value, and then apply `TO_CHAR` with desired format mask to get the final result.

Step-by-step:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as (select 'Tuesday April 27, 2021' from dual),
  3  temp as
  4    -- convert string to DATE using appropriate format mask
  5    (select to_date (col,
  6                     'Day Month dd, yyyy',
  7                     'nls_date_language = english') col
  8       from test
  9    )
 10  -- finally, convert DATE to CHAR using desired format mask
 11  select to_char (col, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') result
 12  from temp;

RESULT
-------------------
2021-04-27T00:00:00

SQL>
```

Or, in a single statement:

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('Tuesday April 27, 2021', 'Day Month dd, yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english'), 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
2021-04-27T00:00:00

SQL>
```